# Can An iOS Device Running An App With Core Bluetooth Connect To An Android Device?

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

Can an iOS device run an app with `core bluetooth`as be used as peripheral to communicate with an Android device which runs an App acting as a `BLE` central role? Can they transfer data？And can iOS can use `Classic bluetooth`to connect to Android devices?

Comment: Yes, you could use BLE. No, you can't use Classic Bluetooth on iOS.

Comment: Thank you. Now, i have an android app, i write a iOS app as peripheral, the android app can scan the iOS peripheral, but i write a iOS app as center, the android app as peripheral, i can not scan the android devices. Did the android app have problem?

Comment: You can use the LightBlue app on iOS. If it can see your Android peripheral then your iOS app has a problem. If it can't then likely your android app has the problem

Comment: yes,that the android app has the problem,the lightBlue app can't see Android peripheral.Thank you.